# GWT dev mode refreshes quickly the first 3-5 times then takes 5 minutes or more beyond

Tags: gwt, dev-mode

Has anybody else noticed that GWT dev mode is able to refresh/reload relatively quickly (10-20sec) for the first 3-5 times then takes 5 plus minutes to reload beyond that?

Comment: I have often come across `OutOfMemoryError` gripes with the dev server in Eclipse, but nothing that a terminate/restart couldn't solve :)

Answer (score 2):

It seems to be a memory related problem.  I added a bunch more RAM to my machine, then gave eclipse more memory in it's ini file and I can go a day of programming without it slowing down.  Here is my ini file

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.2.0.v20110502.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64_1.1.100.v20110502
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256M
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.5
-Xms256m
-Xmx1024m
```